# ElementAt() doesn't work in Linq to SubSonic

Tags: linq, subsonic3

I have this query:

```
var iterator = criteria.binaryAssetBranchNodeIds.GetEnumerator();
iterator.MoveNext();
var binaryAssetStructures = from bas in db.BinaryAssetStructures
                              where bas.BinaryAssetStructureId == iterator.Current
                              select bas;
```

When I iterate over the binaryAssetStructureIds with a foreach loop no problems occur. When I try this

```
var binaryAssetStructure = binaryAssetStructures.ElementAt(0);
```

I get following error:

Unable to cast object of type 'System.Linq.Expressions.MethodCallExpression' to type 'SubSonic.Linq.Structure.ProjectionExpression'

First() for example does work... What am I missing here...

Comment: try binaryAssetStructures.ToList().ElementAt(0) Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know SubSonic at all, but FWIW a similar issue exists with the Entity Framework. In that case it boils down to the fact that there's no direct translation of ElementAt to SQL.

`First()` can be easily translated to `SELECT TOP 1 FROM ... ORDER BY ...`, but the same is not easily expressed for `ElementAt`.

You could argue that e.g. `ElementAt(5)` should be translated to `SELECT TOP 5 FROM ... ORDER BY ...` and then the first four elements simply discarded, but that doesn't work very well if you ask for `ElementAt(100000)`.

In EF, you can partialle overcome this issue forcing the expression to be evaluated first, which can be done with calls to `AsEnumerable`, `ToList` or `ToArray`.

For example

```
var binaryAssetStructure = binaryAssetStructures.AsEnumerable().ElementAt(0);
```

I hope this helps although not explicitly directed at SubSonic.